# Ethernet Cable not detected in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, internet, ethernet

Ubuntu 14.04 does not detect the ethernet lan cable . Windows detects the same ethernet lan cable.  Although ubuntu detects a lan cable which came in the box with router. 
Please help
Here's the output of ethtool eth0:

```
Settings for eth0:
Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 10Mb/s
Duplex: Half
Port: MII
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: d
Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
               drv probe ifdown ifup
Link detected: no
```

sudo lshw -C network:

```
      description: Ethernet interface
      product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0.1
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.1
   logical name: eth0
   version: 14
   serial: 08:9e:01:e1:0a:57
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:62 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b0404000-b0404fff memory:b0400000-b0403fff
```

ifconfig -a :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:9e:01:e1:0a:57  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:626 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:626 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:61833 (61.8 KB)  TX bytes:61833 (61.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:d2:24:a1:1b:4f  
      inet addr:192.168.159.8  Bcast:192.168.159.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::4ad2:24ff:fea1:1b4f/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:63929 errors:0 dropped:719 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7323 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:11495871 (11.4 MB)  TX bytes:1100882 (1.1 MB)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a problem like this before, and the issue was related to Realtek ethernet cards.

Here's how I fixed my issue:

1. ran this command that enabled my Internet access: `sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full`
2. [followed this guide for a permanent fix](https://unixblogger.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/the-pain-of-an-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-ethernet-card/)

Not sure if it'll help you, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 3):

After hours of trials and errors, I finally managed to get the my Ethernet connection working. Here are the steps:

1. Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` ( `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` ), add the following 2 lines:

   ```
   allow-hotplug eth0
   iface eth0 inet dhcp
   ```
2. Install Avahi library:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install libavahi-compat-libdnssd-dev
   ```
3. Edit `/etc/rc.local` ( `gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local` ), add the following line:

   ```
   avahi-autoipd --daemonize --syslog eth0
   ```

   one line above `exit 0`
4. Reboot
5. After reboot, check the network interfaces, by using the command:

   ```
   ifconfig -a
   ```

   `eth0`, `lo`, and `wlan0` should be listed.
   If `eth0:avahi` is also listed (usually with `inet addr:169.254.5.215`), then basically you are ready to go.
   If `eth0:avahi` is NOT listed, then enter the command:

   ```
   sudo avahi-autoipd --daemonize --syslog eth0
   ```

   After some moments, `eth0:avahi` will appear when `ifconfig -a` is run, and you are ready to go. Connect the Ethernet cable on your computer, and you can try ping some IP address on the network.

Comment: Apparently, it was a long term realtek driver issue. Finally i managed to get it resolved through [this link](https://unixblogger.com/2016/08/11/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/) . Still thanks a lot for you answer.