# How do I restart the network interface?

Tags: networking, 16.04

I have recently switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu, but am now unable to connect to the internet. I've been told that it's because my network adapter isn't being recognized (or something like that), and here was step I followed:

https://www.swiftstack.com/docs/install/configure_networking.html

I went through Changing the network configuration, and now I'm stuck at the last bit, restarting the interface. How do I do that? Do I input the command included into the terminal, the etc/network/interfaces file, or GUI?

Comment: Normally, desktop versions of Ubuntu don't use the /etc/network/interfaces file for external interfaces at all - and in any case, if your adapter isn't being recognized then attempting to configure it is putting the cart before the horse. IMHO you should take a step back and explain the *original* issue.

Comment: The guide you linked is evidently written for CentOS and Redhat. There are several major differences between these and Ubuntu. I would not use it.

Comment: Well, according to that link, you need to enter the command in the terminal and press enter. `ifdown` closes the interface, (here `eth0`). `ifdown` opens it.

Answer (score -1):

Internet connection issues are common for dual-booted Windows/Ubuntu. Here is another recent thread with a similar issue ([Ubuntu (dual boot Windows) Ethernet Not Connecting/Detecting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/846125/ubuntu-dual-boot-windows-ethernet-not-connecting-detecting)). If you hadn't already started the procedure you linked to, I would have suggested simply turning off your computer and then turning it back on. To clarify, because people still get this confused, I am not talking about rebooting/restarting. I mean a full shutdown where you have to physically turn your computer back on. I am going to guess that this issue occurred after using Windows. Usually going from Ubuntu to Windows doesn't have this issue.

Comment: No, internet connection issues are seldom if ever related to dual booting. If the hardware has no support it doesn't matter if it's dual or single boot. OSes are independent and each require specific drivers to enable a given hardware. If you actually read the question you linked you would have understood that in spite of the title the issue is at Ubuntu only (and that user is clueless).